# calling CMD with VBS hangs at echo

Tags: vbscript, cmd

im exierience a strange problem.

im trying to call a cmd with a vbs script and it hangs at the uttermost strange point.

heres the oExecShell.StdOut.ReadLine of my cmd that hangs :

```
set targetDir=\\Backupstorage\Servername$\2014-11-28_12-00
if not exist \\Backupstorage\Servername$\2014-11-28_12-00 (mkdir \\Backupstorage\Servername$\2014-11-28_12-00 ) 
Rem Works Fine
 set LogDir=\\\Backupstorage\Servername$\2014-11-28_12-00\Logs 
Rem Does not work for some strange Reason
echo "here" 
"here"
```

and then it hangs, the line that kills it/should follow is :

```
echo %LogDir%
echo "we have the problem"
```

anybody has an?

heres some of the code that starts the cmd :

```
strAction = "C:\makeBackup_test.cmd"
Dim WshShell : Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strAction = Wshshell.expandenvironmentstrings(strAction)
Dim oExecShell : Set oExecShell = WshShell.Exec(strAction)
Do While oExecShell.Status = 0
        WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
writelog("... ExitCode is: " & oExecShell.ExitCode)
LastShellOutput = ""
Do While not(oExecShell.StdOut.AtEndOfStream)
LastShellOutput = LastShellOutput & oExecShell.StdOut.ReadLine & vbCrlf
Loop
writelog("StdOut: " & LastShellOutput)
```

anyone has an idea?

Comment: What happens when you run the batch file directly (without the VBScript wrapper)?

Comment: then it works, thats the strange thing about it. I just dont get why

Comment: Vbs works for me with `strAction = "cmd /C start """" " & """" & Wshshell.expandenvironmentstrings(strAction) & """"` but there is a third backslash in `set LogDir=\\\Backup...` and this cannot be tolerable when used in cmd as an UNC path (although `set` only is good, one may `set` variable to much any character string with almost no limitation)

Comment: The best upshot with `strAction = "cmd /C " & """" & Wshshell.expandenvironmentstrings(strAction) & """"` and `Run` method instead of `Exec` one as follows: `Dim xReturn : xReturn = WshShell.Run( strAction,,True)`. Here `xReturn` value could be tested on type of runned command termination (error code returned by the program or `&hC000013A` if forced by `×` or via task manager etc.)

Comment: @JosefZ That approach requires redirecting the output to a temp file in order to preserve it.

Comment: Try `WScript.Echo oExecShell.StdOut.ReadAll : WScript.Echo oExecShell.StdErr.ReadAll` after the script completed. Also, when posting code samples: do not leave out the part that you actually have problems with. The sample you posted doesn't read anything from the `WshScriptExec` object.

Comment: i Added more of the Run Code as Requested. Loging is allready in Place so im gonna try to capture more using Ansgar's approach

Comment: StdErr is Empty . still the Script hangs at the posted part. gonna play around

Comment: CMD /C solved the Problem. i still dont know why it shouldt work without cmd /c but i wont question it as long as it works :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling int with CMD /C solved it. (strAction = "CMD /C C:\makeBackup_test.cmd")